# Android programming to open Data Usage setting page

Tags: android, android-intent

In Android 5.0 Mobile Data setting is available in Data Usage setting.
I want to open Data Usage setting page in android, but i do not find any Intent to open it. is there any why to open Data Usage setting page

Comment: see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS .. try startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

Comment: but mobile data setting, is now available in Data Usage setting and that's why i want to open that page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
final  Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Maybe in this way:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: 03-05 17:05:57.869: D/MainActivity(16870): Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.Settings } from ProcessRecord{18c735c5 16870:com.example.opendevicesettings/u0a439} (pid=16870, uid=10439) not exported from uid 1001

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS), 0);
```

or this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it will open Network operator setting page  but not  Data Usage setting page. I have Already try this.

Comment: try opening with `ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS` or `ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS`