# Which intent should open Data Usage screen (from settings)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

I wish to open the Data Usage screen from an intent.
I've searched the android.provider.Settings class for an appropriate intent.
Tried :

```
new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS)
new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS)
```

Which doesn't lead to the the data usage.

[image]

I'm well aware of all the links which has this question, but none has a response.
[How to open System Data Usage Activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489414/how-to-open-system-data-usage-activity-in-android)
[Android programming to open Data Usage setting page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873756/android-programming-to-open-data-usage-setting-page)
etc...

Comment: Not all screens in Settings have dedicated `Intent` actions. This may be one of them.

Answer (score 19):

You can use this to achieve the above !! I tested this on **Kitkat** and **lollipop** devices , On both of them its working

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: share your permission aswell

Comment: Works well on Android 5 and 8. On Android 4.1.2, goes to "Data usage" but have no option to enable/disable data. But on this system, we can do it with another way...

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String SETTINGS_PACKAGE = "com.android.settings";
private static final String SETTINGS_CLASS_DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS = "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity";

try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(SETTINGS_PACKAGE, SETTINGS_CLASS_DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setComponent(cn);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Data settings usage Activity is not present");
        }
```