# Android- How to Intent directly to Mobile data usage setting page?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-networking

Android- How to Intent directly to Mobile data usage setting page?

I already tried the following Intents and also its not leads to that page.

```
1. new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS)
2. new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS)
3. new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
```

[image: Mobile data usage setting page]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700842/which-intent-should-open-data-usage-screen-from-settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700842/which-intent-should-open-data-usage-screen-from-settings)

Comment: If anyone gives downvote, please write your view.

Comment: I don't know who did. Sorry

Comment: There is no answers for this question @MD

Comment: That's why i posted as comment

Comment: @VenkateshSelvam It is being so disgusting. I also faced the same many times as one downvotes then downvotes continues to come up even without any comments even the question follows all rules. I support Your question It's clear and better.