# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS }

Tags: android, android-intent, android-data-usage

In my app, I am trying to use Android's `Settings.ACTION_DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS` intent to open the device's **Data usage** screen.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS) for `Settings.ACTION_DATA_USAGE_SETTINGS` says:

> Activity Action: Show settings to allow configuration of data and view
>   data usage.
>
> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you
>   safeguard against this.

I can obviously catch the exception but, when in that situation, is there another intent I can use to open the device's **Data usage** screen?

(NB - I have seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873756/android-programming-to-open-data-usage-setting-page), but none of the suggestions work for me.)

Comment: Not in general. There is no requirement for a device to have such a screen, let alone provide an `Intent` for apps to get to it.

Comment: Some OEMs just don't follow AOSP thoroughly, you must implement per-brand workarounds in that case.

Comment: I forget to add, my device (Samsung Galaxy Core Prime) does have the *Data usage* screen. Is it possible to detect which devices don't provide this intent when my activity starts - so, if there's no workaround, I can then hide the button on such devices?

Comment: You can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`, or `Intent` and `resolveActivity()`.